# This solution would not accept any floats

Tags: c, cs50

Currently on one of the cs50x problem sets 'Cash', which is a simple 'ask for how much change is owed, then calculate how many coins are required' task, so not here asking for a solution but, I don't understand why this won't work.

While it does ask for an input, when I type in a float such as 5.96, it simply hangs. No returns, no errors whatsoever. I have to force it shut. The other thing is the while loop doing the same when set to 0, which is the intended way of doing things in order to get the exact number of coins.

I know how inefficient this code is and there are simpler ways of doing things. I just wish to understand the whys in order to avoid making the same mistakes moving on. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{
    // changes and other containers
    int p = 1;
    int n = 5;
    int d = 10;
    int q = 25;
    int x = 0;
    float c;
    // get how much change is owed in float
    do
    {
        c = get_float("Change owed: ");
    }
    while (c < 0);
    // int conversion to avoid imprecision
    int a = round(c * 100);
    // 1 because 0 spits out an unknown error
    while (a >= 1)
    {
        // if the converted amount is bigger than a quarter
        if (a >= q)
        {
            // x = number of coins, a = amount left
            x = a / q;
            a = a % q;
        }

        else if (a >= d)
        {
            x = x + a / d;
            a = a - a % d;
        }

        else if (a >= n)
        {
            x = x + a / n;
            a = a - a % n;
        }

        else
        {
            x = x + a / p;
            a = a - a % p;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", x);
    printf("%i\n", a);
}
```

Comment: You need to debug this. You'll discover your logic for things like `a = a - a % d;` is *wrong*.

Comment: You're a star. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please create an answer to this question, in order to get it out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Alright got it.

Comment: regarding: `int a = round(c * 100);` the function: `round()` expects a `double` parameter and returns a `double` value..  Trying to stuff that double value into a `int` is error prone.  Suggest using: `100.0` and `floor()`

Comment: Thanks for the floor() suggestion. It seems more sound than round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to WhozCraig, I figured out that my logic was at fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{
    // changes and other containers
    int p = 1;
    int n = 5;
    int d = 10;
    int q = 25;
    int x = 0;
    float c;
    // get how much change is owed in float
    do
    {
        c = get_float("Change owed: ");
    }
    while (c < 0);
    // int conversion to avoid imprecision
    int a = round(c * 100);
    // 1 because 0 spits out an unknown error
    while (a >= 1)
    {
        // if the converted amount is bigger than a quarter
        if (a >= q)
        {
            // x = number of coins, a = amount left
            x = a / q;
            a = a % q;
        }

        else if (a >= d)
        {
            x = x + a / d;
            a = a % d;
        }

        else if (a >= n)
        {
            x = x + a / n;
            a = a % n;
        }

        else
        {
            x = x + a / p;
            a = a % p;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", x);
    printf("%i\n", a);
}
```

Comment: `int a = round(c * 100);` is a reasonable conversion.  Consider `long a = lround(c * 100.0);` to better handle corner cases. `c * 100` may be inexact and so  begin  [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding).  `c * 100.0` is far more likely to be exact.

Comment: I had no idea about the lround and double rounding. This is much appreciated. Thanks.